# sorting dictionary based on two constraints

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, dictionary, anonymous-function

I am trying to sort the values in a dictionary (Word objects) based on two constraints. The Word objects have two relevant fields: `Int: count` and `Bool: pinned`. These constraints are as follows: first if the word is pinned (i.e. `value.pinned = true`), I want the word to appear first in the sorted array regardless of its `count` field. If the word is not pinned, then I want the word to be sorted based on its `count` value among other unpinned words in decreasing order.

I ended up implementing the sorting function like this:

```
sortedWordsArr = wordsDict.sorted {
    if $0.value.pinned {
        return $0.value.pinned && !$1.value.pinned
    } else {
        return $0.value.count > $1.value.count
    }
}
```

However, this does not seem to do the job. When I pin words, they don't move to the beginning of the array. They seem to shuffle around randomly, and sometimes not at all. I've browsed forums that seem to answer this question of how to sort using multiple constraints, but I'm still not too sure how to set the `sorted` closure up for my constraints.

It seems to me that this first condition: `return $0.value.pinned && !$1.value.pinned` compares a pinned word `$0` to a not necessarily pinned object `$1` since `$1` is just specified to be another word, not necessarily a pinned one in my dictionary. Is this line of thought incorrect? If so, how can I sort my dictionary correctly based on these constraints?

Thank you for reading this post- appreciative of any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `Bool` to return a `value` that is comparable like `1` for `true` and `0` for `false` and just compare a tuple to sort them using descending order. Note that this will sort the pinned elements that are true in descending order as well which I am not sure if you would like to sort or not:

---

```
extension Bool {
    var value: Int { self ? 1 : 0 }
}
```

---

```
let sorted = wordsDict.sorted(by: {
    ($0.value.pinned.value, $0.value.count) > ($1.value.pinned.value, $1.value.count)
})
```

---

If you would like to keep the original count order of the pinned values. Note that a dictionary is an unordered collection:

```
let sorted = wordsDict.sorted(by: {
    if $0.value.pinned { return true }
    if !$0.value.pinned && $1.value.pinned { return false }
    return $0.value.count > $1.value.count
})
```

of using the ternary operator syntax

```
let sorted = wordsDict.sorted(by: {
    $0.value.pinned ? true :
    !$0.value.pinned && $1.value.pinned ? false :
    $0.value.count > $1.value.count
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! As for the first sorted function, what is the protocol for sorting a tuple? Does it sort based on the first entry (`$0.value.pinned.value < $1.value.pinned.value`) first and then if this entry is the same, sort based on the second entry?

Comment: @rjc810 tuples are `Comparable` since Swift 3 AFAIR as long as all of its elements conform to `Comparable`. It is up to 6 elements. `Bool` does NOT conform to `Comparable` thats why I am adding a value `Int` to them. It will compare the first element, if they are equal, it will compare the next element and so on